# Update ViewModel if Model changed

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

How can i update view model when model change. First solution that i found was subscribe in ViewModel for PropertyChangedEvent of Model. But is it good way? Maybe it exist better way to Notify ViewModel?

Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding SomeValue}"/>
        <Label Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Second}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
namespace WpfApplication
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    Model model = new Model();
    public ViewModel()
    {
        model.PropertyChanged += (o, e) =>
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(e.PropertyName));
        };
    }
    public int SomeValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.model.SomeValue;
        }

        set
        {
            this.model.SomeValue = value;
        }
    }

    public int Second
    {
        get
        {
            return this.model.Second;
        }

        set
        {
            this.model.Second = value;
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int someValue;

    public int SomeValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.someValue;
        }

        set
        {
            this.someValue = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SomeValue");
        }
    }

    private int second;

    public int Second
    {
        get
        {
            return this.second;
        }

        set
        {
            this.second = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Second");
        }
    }

    public Model()
    {
        Action Test = new Action(WorkAsync);
        IAsyncResult result = Test.BeginInvoke(null,null);
    }

    public void WorkAsync()
    {
        while(true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
            SomeValue += 1;
            Second += 1;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SomeValue");
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "But is it good way?" - yes, this is widespread approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your model does not necessarily *need* to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, a *pure* MVVM approach would be to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the **View Model** and expose only properties of which the view **requires** of the Model.

In your case, it'll look like this:

```
public class Model 
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Model _model = new Model();

    public int SomeModelValue
    {
        get { return _model.SomeValue; }
        set 
        {
            _model.SomeValue = value;
            //Notify property changed
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

And your view will bind to `SomeModelValue`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeModelValue}" ... />
```

The benefit of this approach is that your view model is **not** exposing the entire model to the view, and only properties of the model that need to be exposed will be *seen* by the view. It also allows your model to remain *relatively* dumb.

Comment: If i should remove INotify from model, property that change in model not in ViewModel should not Notify ViewModel to change. You approach right if data changes in ViewModel not in model.

Comment: I'd say, that one doesn't need `INPC` in model until model doesn't contain any asynchronous operations, that could change its state regardless of view model.

Comment: If the View Model needs to update properties in the model (that need to notify the view) then it should update the **view model property** (which exposes the model property to the view) instead of the model property directly. @Dennis is right, there may be an instance where the view model is not responsible for changing the model property, in which case a notification will need to occur from the model to the view model.

Answer (score 0):

create a raisepropertychanged method/call it

enforce two way binding on the control

[look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13530262/wpf-mvvm-two-way-updates)

[and here](https://acrocontext.wordpress.com/2014/03/09/c-how-raisepropertychanged-works-in-mvvm-light/)
[and here is best](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/682124/Safest-way-to-use-RaisePropertyChanged-method)

[xaml two way binding](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37250/One-Way-Two-Way-and-One-Time-Bindings-using-Silver#Twowaybinding)